# Sticky div dont stick at top at scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I want that my div called: top will stick on the top if i scroll down, but right now it don't stick at the top.

I am using jQuery with this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 5) {
          $('#top').addClass('.fixed').FadeIn(200);
      } else {
          $('#top').removeClass('.fixed');
      }
  });
```

Does someone know where the problem is?

Comment: arguments of `.addClass()` don't need the `.` so should be `.addClass('fixed')` instead of `.addClass('.fixed')`

Comment: It's "fadeIn", not "FadeIn"

Comment: fadeIn and FadeIn are the same @DenysSéguret

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not add `.` for the class names inside `addClass()`. Try this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 5) {
     $('#top').addClass('fixed').FadeIn(200);
   } else {
     $('#top').removeClass('fixed');
   }
 });
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @JackZelig Add class doesn't have a `.`

Comment: Fair enough. I think I'm going blind :)